# Iteratively printing full binary tree

Tags: c#, .net, binary-tree

**Underlying problem resolved**: When nothing makes sense, make sure your code is as isolated as you think it is.  The delay wasn't in the routine itself, it was in copying the result to a textbox. Not sure what's going on there, but at least now it makes sense. Sorry for wasting people's time! Because I'm so weak in this area, though, I'd still love to see an iterative implementation of this, so I'll leave this question open for now.

I have a full binary tree of the form:

```
root
 /\
1  node
    /\
   2  3
```

What I would like to do is print it as "(1,(2,3))", but using an iterative algorithm, since the recursive algorithm I was using has inexplicably slowed by a factor of ten to several hundred on larger trees, despite absolutely no changes in the code or relevant parts of the tree. (It's clearly the recursing itself that's the problem, so I'm assuming it has something to do with stack issues, though I'm honestly at a loss on that issue as well.)

I've been poking at the logic all afternoon using variations of traditional iterative tree-walking logic, and I just cannot get it working. Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I'm working in C#, but I really just need an algorithm, so examples in any .NET language should do.

**Update**: The original, recursive code was simply this. IsBaseGem is an auto-implemented bool, and ID is an auto-implemented string.

```
private string DoFullCombine() => this.Component1.DoSubCombine() + "+" + this.Component2.DoSubCombine();
private string DoSubCombine() => this.IsBaseGem ? this.ID : "(" + this.DoFullCombine() + ")";
```

Current, iterative code, which is very obviously broken at this point, since it never terminates:

```
public string GetFullCombine()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var gemStack = new Stack<Gem>();
    Gem gem = this;
    while (gem != null)
    {
        while (!gem.IsBaseGem)
        {
            sb.Append('(');
            gemStack.Push(gem);
            gem = gem.Component1;
        }

        sb.Append(gem.ID);
        sb.Append('+');
        gem = gemStack.Pop().Component2;
        if (gem.IsBaseGem)
        {
                sb.Append(gem.ID);
                sb.Append(')');
                gem = gemStack.Pop();
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's the building of the string and not the actual tree traversal that slows you down. Can you post what you have now?

Comment: Why do you think the recursive algorithm is much slower due to it being recursive? A typical iterative approach would be to devise a stack to keep track of where in the tree the algorithm is on each iteration.

Comment: I assumed it was the building of the string as well at first, because I was just using a traditional concatenation. I switched to a static StringBuilder, though, and achieved speed improvements of only 200ms on an 8-second run. There's literally nothing else in this method besides the string building, so I would've expected a noticeable improvement if it were the string building that was the problem. I'll post code shortly, just stopping by quickly right now.

Comment: @lurker: Yes, I know a stack is the appropriate approach, but that's what I can't get working. See my above response for why it seems the recursion is the problem rather than the string building.

Comment: Code is now posted above, both the recursive and iterative versions. The point where the recursive version begins to slow down noticeably is about 16k nodes, with a recursion depth typically in the teens and twenties, but sometimes getting close to 40. I'm at a loss for why the recursive method craps out now when older versions don't on the very same tree.

Comment: Maybe the data is bad.  You could have a loop in the tree which will cause it to run forever.

Comment: Good thought, but I've confirmed that the tree is identical to the one generated by older versions of the code, which work near-instantaneously. Whatever the case, I'd still like to see an algorithm to generate the above output, though, cuz I just can't figure it out. Recursion isn't my strong suit to begin with, much less faking it with an iterative method.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why recursive algorithm should be that much slower. EDIT now it is clear problem was somewhere else, but I will keep it here as reference.

```
private void DoFullCombine(StringBuilder sb)
{
    this.Component1.DoSubCombine(sb);
    sb.Append("+");
    this.Component2.DoSubCombine(sb);
}
private void DoSubCombine(StringBuilder sb)
{
    if (this.IsBaseGem)
    {
        sb.Append(this.ID);
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append("(");
        this.DoFullCombine(sb);
        sb.Append(")");
    };
}
```

**EDIT**

I made non recursive version. It is about the same speed as the recursive variant. The most tricky were the parentheses, I push null on the stack to mark where they should be.

```
   public string GetFullCombineNonRecur()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var gemStack = new Stack<Gem>();
        Gem gem = this;
        int level = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            while (!gem.IsBaseGem)
            {
                sb.Append('('); level++;
                gemStack.Push(gem);
                gem = gem.Component1;
            }

            sb.Append(gem.ID);

            do
            {
                if (level == 0)
                {
                    if (gem != this) { sb.Remove(0, 1).Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1); }
                    return sb.ToString();
                }
                gem = gemStack.Pop();
                if (gem == null) // is ")" mark
                {
                    sb.Append(')'); level--;
                }
            } while (gem == null);

            sb.Append('+');
            gemStack.Push(null); // push ")" mark here
            gem = gem.Component2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I already have, and it produced only a marginal gain. To be safe, though, I retried it with your code and it still produced similar timings.

The only thing I can think of at this point is that I'm using VS Community Update 1 RC 1...maybe it's got some bizarre bug in it that only hit me at some point recently? Seems highly unlikely, but I can't see any other explanation.